# Qual a importancia do weak e unowned no swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

Estou estudando swift faz algum tempo e agora estou querendo me aprofundar na linguagem e na plataforma IOS.

Queria saber de forma mais concreta qual é a importância e qual a forma correta de usar o weak e unowned.

Answer (score 1):

Essas referencias têm a ver com o ARC. Na prática estás a indicar ao compilador que tipo de referencia é aquela variável para ele conseguir evitar referencias circulares.

Tipicamente tens strong, weak e unowned.

- Strong protege o ponteiro de ser deallocado pelo ARC. Enquanto alguma coisa tiver uma referencia a um tipo de objeto strong, não é dealocado. Isto leva a retain cycles. Tens dois objetos com referencias strong, nenhum vai ser dealocado.
- Weak Faz o contrário.  Não proteje o ponteiro de ser dealocado.  Um exemplo deste tipo de objetos são os IBActions. Imagina se não fossem do tipo weak. Terias vários problemas.
- Unowned é igual ao tipo weak mas não pode ser optional. O tipo weak, quando é dealocado fica com o valor nil. Unowned é utilizado quando sabes que nunca vai ser nil.

Existe mais teoria por tras desta questão, mas esta é a básica.